# How to change sender name in Outlook ?

Tags: vba, outlook

I am sending an email using `Outlook` object from a subroutine `vba`

The email gets send from my email and the recipients see : `myemail@xxx.com` . Is there any way I can make those recipients get an email that would have `MyfirstName MylastName` instead of my email

```
Sub Mail_Workbook_1()

    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .From = "MyfirstName MylastName" 'something like this
        .To = "ron@debruin.nl"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "This is the Subject line"
        .Body = "Hello World!"
    ....
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are sending through Exchange on behalf of another mailbox, set the `MailItem.SentOnBehalfOfName` property (assuming you have sufficient privileges)

If you are sending through a particular SMTP account, set the `MailItem.SendUsingAccount` property.

If you need to send as an arbitrary SMTP user, see [this example](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/faq.htm#14) on my website - you will essentially need to set the "From" named MAPI property in the PS_INTERNET_HEADERS namespace. Note that not all SMTP servers will let you do that - Exchange for one will not let you spoof the sender.

If you want to send as one of the alias (proxy) SMTP addresses belonging to a particular Exchange mailbox, you will need to send through SMTP - sending through OOM or MAPI  will always send with the default SMTP address of the mailbox. For an end user, you can configure a dummy POP3/SMTP account or use a product like [Proxy Manager](http://www.dimastr.com/proxyman/) (I am its author). See [MSOutlook.info](http://www.msoutlook.info/question/send-mail-from-additional-exchange-address-or-alias) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I am using Exchange. With respect to my code above, should I be using : `OutMail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "MyfirstName MylastName" ` ?

Comment: Yes. Anything that can be uniquely resolved to the name of the person you are trying to send on behalf of. Keep in mind you must have an explicit permission to send on behalf of that user.