# How can I change sender in an outlook mailitem?

Tags: powershell, outlook

I inherited a script that goes through a shared inbox and will do a replyAll on the message, change some things, and then save it to the drafts folder. It is using the outlook.application com object in powershell. One of the first things we do is to change the sender in Outlook to our own email address instead of the shared mailbox account.

In Outlook, if we use the pull down and select the correct account and then send it works. However, I want to do this in the script as we often forget to do it manually.

I have a powershell object and have successfully changed it to use my account to send from:

```
$mailitem = $message.replyAll()
$mailitem.sendUsingAccount = $myacct
```

However, when I send the message, the from address is still set to the shared account.

I've also tried adding

```
$mailitem.SentOnBehalfOfName = "foo@bar.com"
$mailitem.Sender = "foo@bar.com"
```

with the same issue.

I'm hoping y'all might have some ideas on how to make this work.

Edit: Looks like [How to change sender name in Outlook ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376859/how-to-change-sender-name-in-outlook) is closely related to this ticket. Not sure it is a duplicate though. My question here is around the difference between what the pulldown does to set my account in the outlook client and what I'm trying to do in the powershell script. If it works in the outlook client it should work in the powershell script. If the problem is SentOnBehalfOfName attribute, why wouldn't I have permissions to change it? I'm changing it to my email address.

Comment: `$mailitem.SentOnBehalfOfName` should work, but it seems you need to activate appropriate permission at Exchange (tried it and had an e-mail in my Outlook that my user hasn't the needed permissions).

Comment: So, if you don't have permissions I would expect an error email in my mailbox, right? I haven't seen any of those. It will still save to my drafts. It still "looks like" the mail is coming from the correct account, it just sets the from to the wrong address

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change sender name in Outlook ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23376859/how-to-change-sender-name-in-outlook)

Comment: Not a duplicate... Why would outlook client be able to set the mail account a message comes from via a pull down, but the powershell can't? I'm merely trying to send the mail as my normal account instead of an shared inbox.